# Substrate VM: Unable to launch the native image generator

Tags: graalvm

I wanted to check out the **mx** image generator:

```
./mx image -cp $PWD/svmbuild -H:Class=HelloWorld -H:Name=helloworld
mx: unknown command 'image'
```

It seems that the "image" command is not available (anymore?) 
Any replacement available?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an `mx native-image` command.

The README file in the [GraalVM project repository](https://github.com/oracle/graal/tree/master/substratevm) lists the following quick start snippet:

```
cd substratevm
mx build

echo "public class HelloWorld { public static void main(String[] args) { 
System.out.println(\"Hello World\"); } }" > HelloWorld.java
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac HelloWorld.java
mx native-image HelloWorld
./helloworld
```

Allegedly, one needs a JDK 8 with the JVMCI for this to work, here's a relevant quote from the README:

> Install mx and point JAVA_HOME to a labsjdk.
>
> For compilation native-image depends on the local toolchain, so make
>   sure: glibc-devel, zlib-devel (header files for the C library and
>   zlib) and gcc are available on your system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have installed GraalVM CE and put it into the PATH and JAVA_HOME:
`java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build .8.0_192-20181024121959.buildslave.jdk8u-src-tar--b12) GraalVM 1.0.0-rc10 (build 25.192-b12-jvmci-0.53, mixed mode)`

`~/mx-master:$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/francesco/graalvm-ce-1.0.0-rc10`
Is this what you mean to point to a labsjdk?

Comment: A "labsjdk" is a regular JDK 8 with the addition of JVMCI (CI = Compiler interface) that allows the replacement of the top tier compiler and plug the Graal compiler instead of the Hotspot one. You can download it here : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oracle-labs/program-languages/downloads/index.html
Java versions >8 are bundled with JVMCI, so no need of a modified JDK if you use JDK11 for instance.